# Obtener cookie en el navegador - Node JS, JWT, cookie-parser

Tags: nodejs, jwt, cookies, autenticación

Hola a todos me encuentro en apuros debido a que me encuentro realizando un login con autenticación y ya tengo todo configurado pero por alguna razón la cookie con el token no llega a mi navegador, aquí mi código:

```
const { verify } = require("../utils/handleBcrypt");
const { generateToken } = require("../utils/handleJWT");
const handleError = require("../utils/handleError");

exports.login = (req, res) => {
  let { username, password } = req.body;

  try {
    req.getConnection((err, conn) => {
      if (err) return res.send(err);

      conn.query(
        `SELECT * FROM sigin WHERE username = ?`,
        [username],
        async (err, result) => {
          if (
            result.length === 0 ||
            !(await verify(password, result[0].password))
          ) {
            res.status(403);
            res.send("Usuario y/o contraseña incorrecta");
          } else {
            // Inicio de sessión OK
            const id = result[0].id;
            const token = generateToken(id);

            res.cookie("access_token", token, {
              maxAge: 3600,
              httpOnly: true,
            });

            res.send("Conexión exitosa");
          }
        }
      );
    });
  } catch (error) {
    handleError(res, "ERROR_POST_LOGIN");
  }
};
```

En este primer archivo lo que monto es el controlador para el inicio de sesión el cual le valido la contraseña hasheada y luego si todo va bien me ejecuta la acción del token el cual va dentro de una cookie.

```
const { sign, verify } = require("jsonwebtoken");
const JWT_SECRET = process.env.JWT_SECRET || "token.010101";

const generateToken = (id) => {
  const jwt = sign({ id }, JWT_SECRET);
  return jwt;
};

const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.cookies.access_token;
  if (!token) return res.send(403);

  const data = verify(jwt, JWT_SECRET);
  req.userId = data.id;
  return next();
};

module.exports = { generateToken, verifyToken };
```

En este segundo archivo lo único que hago es configurar las funciones que usare con jwt, cabe aclarar que el módulo de cookie-parser ya se encuentra configurado en el archivo principal del proyecto y se ve algo así:

```
app.use(cookieParser());
```

Después de todo esto no logro recibir la cookie con el token en el navegador no sé qué me hacer falta por configurar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

agradezco si alguien me puede ayudar.

Comment: si la peticion es a `127.0.0.1` ( o `::1`) no la vas a ver en `localhost`

Comment: No te entiendo lo que me quieres decir la petición está en localhost porque las pruebas las estoy realizando en local y esa dirección es la que toma mysql no ?

Comment: si cargas el form de login via `localhost` y la validación se hace contra `127.0.0.1` la cookie no la vas a ver pq la cookie es de `127.0.0.1` revisa esa parte, la url del `fetch` o `post` en el frontend

Comment: Claro en mi cliente lo tengo apuntando al local donde está alojado mi api, mira : axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/login`)  de esta manera lo tengo.